I was attempting to upgrade from Craft 3.9.13 to 4 but I'm running into an error
Has anyone ever seen this one? Any tips?
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'licenseKeyStatus' in 'field list'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT `id`, `handle`, `version`, `schemaVersion`, `licenseKeyStatus`, `licensedEdition`, `installDate`
FROM `craft_plugins`
ORDER BY `handle`
Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 42S22
    [1] => 1054
    [2] => Unknown column 'licenseKeyStatus' in 'field list'
)
↵
Caused by: PDOException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'licenseKeyStatus' in 'field list'
in /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php at line 1302

1. in /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.phpat line 676

